# TitleView is not displayed

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I have a Xamarin.Forms application supporting UWP. On all pages, I have added a TitleView with a Label:

```
        var page = (Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType);

        Label titleViewLabel = new Label
        {
            Text = item.Title,
            FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold,
            FontSize = 25,
            TextColor = Color.White,
            BackgroundColor = backgroundColor,
            Margin = 10
        };

        NavigationPage.SetTitleView(page, titleViewLabel);
```

Now one of my pages has a nice title "Products".

This page has a ListView of Products, and upon clicking any item in it, we navigate to a ProductDetailPage:

```
    private async void ProductView_OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Product product = (Product)args.SelectedItem;
        ProductDetailPage productDetailPage = new ProductDetailPage
        {
            BindingContext = product,
            Title = product.Name
        };

        await Navigation.PushAsync(productDetailPage);
    }
```

As we set Title to the Product's Name, the previous title 'Products" is replaced with a specific Product Name. It is OK, but when I press the button Back to navigate again to the Products page. But the title stays empty. I debugged it, and can see that the TitleView still contains text "Products":

```
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

        Label titleView = ((Label)NavigationPage.GetTitleView(this));
        // titleView.Text has "Products!!
    }
```

How can I make the title show up?

Comment: Maybe this gives you a hint? https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4292

Comment: @Gerald Versluis Thank you for your suggestion. It seems though that for that person TitleView did not appear at all, but for me it is hidden only when I come back to that page...

Comment: Ah noted! Might just as well be another bug :)

Comment: Have you tried, just for debugging purposes, to oonly set the titleview on OnAppearing?

Comment: @Bruno Caceiro Are you talking about the ProductsPage or the ProductDetailPage?

Comment: ProductsPage, your problem is only in that page, correct?

Comment: @Bruno Caceiro I tried it. The TitleView did not appear upon returning to that page...

Comment: I am using a Mac, so I can't make a small project to test that. I suggest opening a bug in XamarinForms github page

Comment: @Bruno Caceiro Could you please give me a link? I cannot find there where I can report a bug.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues